# Node.js and PowerShell Commands/Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here is the folder structure for my node.js project:

```
MySampleApp\
MySampleApp\Package.json
MySampleApp\Server.js
MySampleApp\public:
    index.html - Invoked when server.js starts and shows "Click Me" button
    fetchprocess.js - check button click and then show in DocumentElementID
    user1.ps1 - runs Get-Process command to fetch processes
```

fetchprocess.js:

```
console.log('Client-side code running');
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
console.log('button was clicked');
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "ClickedNow";

    var ps = new shell({
       executionPolicy: 'bypass',
       noProfile: true
    });

   app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   ps.addCommand("./user.ps1", [ {
   name: 'guid', value: req.params.guid
} ])
    ps.invoke().then(output => {
    res.end(output);  // This is to show the output in web browser
   })
})

});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <p id="counter">Loading button click data.</p>
   <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
 </body>
 <script src="fetchprocess.js"></script>
</html>
```

My objective is to execute "user1.ps1" when someone clicks on the "ClickMe" button and then show the data in HTML Div (Counter). When I try to run above code it throws an error that require is not defined in fetchprocess.js file.

Image:

[image]
I will have several scripts under the public folder that will be executed when someone clicks on other buttons on the web app. What is the best folder structure for such project.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR; There is no way you can execute Node.js code in a browser.

Looks like you messaged up with libraries. You are trying to execute some Node.js code in the browser.

```
 <script src="fetchprocess.js"></script>
```

Here you are loading the script in the browser. The truth is that Browser JS code does not have access to the platform things like PowerShell and it is not Node.js at all. If you need to execute Node.js code use Node.js executable.

UPD:
The workaround may be the following.

1. Spin up HTTP server locally with Node.js
2. Add an endpoint that runs the PS script once it receives a request.
3. On-click send AJAX request to your server.

But it worth noticing that it will work only on the machine where the Node.js server is running. Because **it is not possible to run PowerShell from a browser**.

Comment: here is the link that explains how to execute PowerShell scripts via Node.js 
 https://www.jeansnyman.com/posts/executing-powershell-commands-in-a-nodejs-api/

Comment: I am not executing Node.js code in browser. I am calling an existing powershell script by using node-powershell module with a click of button. I think that's doable.

Comment: have updated question with error that I am receiving when clicking on "Click Me" button.

Comment: It is not doable. You can not call `node-powershell` module in a browser, because this module is expected to be executed in Node.js and not in the Browser. That is why you see `require` is not a defined issues, because browser JS code does not have the global function `require`.
The workaround could be to create HTTP server and call the PS1 script from the server when the client calls you.

Comment: Well yes, where do you want to get `shell` class from? Browser does not have such a thing as a `shell` defined. :)

Comment: Also, you are showing the link that tells you how to run PS scrips via **Node.js** whereas your code in the example is executed in the **Browser**, so you can not run PS script from a Browser. Node.js and Browser are different things.

Comment: I see. Can you correct below script? My objective is to call a PowerShell script from a button click. Thank you.

Comment: I can not correct it, because **it is not possible** to call `PowerShell` script from the browser. :) 
I will put pseudocode in my answer for you on how to do more advanced things, that could be workaround.

Comment: So are you saying that example provided in this post https://www.jeansnyman.com/posts/executing-powershell-commands-in-a-nodejs-api/ can only work on local machine and do not work when I move my app to a node.js hosting provider or an Azure VM?

Comment: If you host the same Node.js code it will work on the Azure VM, but it won't execute the PowerShell script on the client computer who downloads your HTML page. What I am trying to say that you can not call PowerShell code from a browser on a client machine. You need to use Node.js for that, and you can run it on your Azure VM, but this will work only on this particular VM where the Node.js is running.

Comment: So all I need is data from the PowerShell script that executes on the Node.js server (inside the VM) then the data (output) should be send to browser as a response. Once response is received from the server (output) I would use a javascript to parse the data and then append to a div. So what I was requesting here is to help me with a server side and client side code that can execute a powershell script (hosted on the server) and return the data.

Comment: Example posted in above link works just fine and I can see processes in the browser as a response from the server but what if I need to collect processes with a button click??

Comment: The only way you can do that is to use the HTTP server. And send HTTP request to the back-end and handle the logic you need in the HTTP request handler. You can use express server for that.

Comment: Thought of using get request but how does server knows that a particular HTML DIV needs to be filled with the data. I already have an html table that needs to be filled with the data.